# What is the state-of-the-art regarding sampling from discrete distribution?

Tags: sampling, discrete-data, gibbs

After struggling with auto-Poisson model (a.k.a. Random Markov Network with conditional Poisson distributions) trying to force Gibbs sampler to obtain discrete sample of the network (since I know conditional distributions) I realized that I have never seen discrete version of this sampler.

I wonder what is the state-of-the-art regarding sampling from discrete distribution (not confined to Bayesian posterior sampling)? Is there something like Gibbs sampler to sample from conditional discrete distributions?

Comment: Gibbs sampling can be used for discrete distributions as well, under appropriate considerations. This in mentioned, for instance, in the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling#Implementation), "Implementation" section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very puzzling question: the Gibbs sampler draws its name from Gibbs random fields where it was originally used by the Geman brothers to generate realisations from such ***discrete*** models. For instance the Ising model is made of a vector of random variables each taking values in $\{-1,1\}$...

So indeed the Gibbs can be used for discrete models. And I do not understand why you have to ***force*** your "Gibbs sampler to obtain discrete samples". If you are using the proper full conditionals they should be on a discrete support.

Comment: Thank you Xi'an. I was just a bit confused and had some misunderstanding about Markov random fields. But know, thanks to your answer here and comment at my another question, all this seems to make perfect sense.